# How to convert true false values in dataframe as 1 for true and 0 for false

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

How to convert true false values in Dataframe as 1 for true and 0 for false

```
COL1  COL2 COL3  COL4
12   TRUE  14    FALSE
13   FALSE  13    TRUE


OUTPUT
12   1  14 0
13   0  13 1
```

Answer (score 43):

First, if you have the strings `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'`, you can convert those to boolean `True` and `False` values like this:

```
df['COL2'] == 'TRUE'
```

That gives you a `bool` column. You can use `astype` to convert to `int` (because `bool` is an integral type, where `True` means `1` and `False` means `0`, which is exactly what you want):

```
(df['COL2'] == 'TRUE').astype(int)
```

To replace the old string column with this new `int` column, just assign it:

```
df['COL2'] = (df['COL2'] == 'TRUE').astype(int)
```

And to do that to two columns at one, just index with a list of columns:

```
df[['COL2', 'COL4']] = (df[['COL2', 'COL4']] == 'TRUE').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 20):

Simply doing this:

```
df[["col2", "col4"]] *= 1
```

Python considers boolean values (True, False) like (1, 0) respectively.
So you can operate with it like numbers.

Answer (score 5):

You could convert the type of each column like

```
In [7]: df[['COL2', 'COL4']] = df[['COL2', 'COL4']].astype(int)

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
0    12     1    14     0
1    13     0    13     1
```

Even `df[['COL2', 'COL4']].astype(float)` works for conversion.

Comment: That's just going to raise `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'TRUE'`.

Comment: It's working for me on `'0.14.0'`  @abarnert and hence I pasted the console output. Does the newer version throws this error? Ah, I think, I've taken initial True/False as Boolean values not strings!

Comment: Yeah, it's not exactly clear from his question, but if his DF is printing out as `TRUE` and `FALSE` that has to be the strings `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` (or something else whose repr looks like that, maybe).

Answer (score 5):

Suppose `d` is the dataframe you want to convert

```
f = lambda x: 1 if x==True else 0
```

`d.applymap(f)` should be what you want.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `df[["col2", "col4"]].applymap(int)`

Answer (score 4):

This does not work:

```
df['COL2'] = (df['COL2'] == 'TRUE').astype(int)
```

This works:

```
df['COL2'] = (df['COL2'] == True ).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> df=pd.DataFrame(data={'col1' : [True, False, True],
>                  'col2': [14, 15, 12],
>                  'col3': [False, True, True]})
> df[['col1', 'col3']]=df[['col1', 'col3']].astype('int')
> df
> ```

```
Output:
    col1    col2    col3
0   1        14      0
1   0        15      1
2   1        12      1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following method:

```
variable_name = {'True' : 0 , 'False' : 1 }

data['Column_name'] = data['Column_name'].map(Variable_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas.DataFrame.replace

```
>>> df

   COL1   COL2  COL3   COL4
0    12   TRUE    14  FALSE
1    13  FALSE    13   TRUE

>>> df.replace(['TRUE','FALSE'],[1,0])

   COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
0    12     1    14     0
1    13     0    13     1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a categorical column in your data (such as country name) `.astype(int)` will return an error
A better choice is to multiply your data with one

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header = None) 
data *= 1 # make true/false -> 1/0
print(data)
```

so if you have

```
True False USA
False False USA
True True russia
```

result will be

```
1 0 USA
0 0 USA
1 1 USA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this to convert the boolean values like True or False to 1 or 0.

```
    In [2] : df['attribute_name']
    Out[2] : 0 True
             1 False
             2 True
             3 True
```

Now import these packages:

```
    In [3] : from sklearn import preprocessing
             lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
             lab_enc.fit(df['attribute_name'])
             variable = lab_enc.transform(df['attribute_name'])
             df['variable'] = variable
             print df['variable']
    Out[4] : 0 1
             1 0
             2 1
             3 1
```

If you want to revert back the values from 0 or 1 to False or True you can use lab_encoder.inverse_transform([0,1]) which results the output from 0 or 1 to False or True

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the **'True'** and **'False'** values (**strings**) to **1** and **0** respectively for a specific **column** (here we choose 3rd column) as follows.

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df
data = df(data) # where data contains your data as rows and columns
                # and it is converted to dataframe using pandas (ignore if already df)
for i in range(len(data[3])):
    if data[3][i] == 'TRUE':
        data[3][i] = 1
    elif data[3][i] == 'FALSE':
        data[3][i] = 0
    else:
        pass
```

This method can be used to compare any value or string and replace that location with the required value or string.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and clean way to do this is using `numpy's where` function

```
df['Y'] = np.where(df['X'] == "SOME_VALUE", 1, 0)
```

will internally calculate **True/False** for values and replace them with **1/0** creating a array of ones and zeros.

Similarly,

```
df['Y'] = np.where((df['X'] == "SOME_VALUE") & (df['Z'] == "SOME_VALUE"), 100, 0)
```

works like a charm and is quite similar to Ms Excel calculations making it intuitive.